# How to handle the data in content script when chrome extension is disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, content-script

I want the content script to handle data even when the extension is disabled and send that handled data to the service worker once the extension is enabled again.Whatever approaches came to my mind needs to deal with the service worker but I cannot access the service worker when the extension is disabled.I read somewhere that even when the extension is disabled service worker and the and the content script remains alive just the communication channel between them gets terminated. However I am not getting how can I proceed further.